# How can I use autocomplete with event binding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form where I can add fields that have autocomplete.
Instead of adding the autocomplete to each field as I create them, is it possible to use event binding to add the autocomplete?
I am new when it comes to events in Javascript.
This is what I have done to add a new line, using event binding (works perfectly):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=addItem]')
        .bind('click', function() {
            var line = $('#list > div').size()+1;
            divId = 'line-'+line;
            var divCloned = $('#line-1').clone();
            divCloned.attr('id', divId);
            $('#list').append(divCloned);
            var inputs = $(divCloned).children('input').get();
            for (var i in inputs) {
                inputs[i].value='';
                inputs[i].id = inputs[i].id.replace(/\d+/, line);
                inputs[i].name = inputs[i].name.replace(/\d+/, line);
            }
            this.blur();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your autocomplete to be applied to all input fields? You can do that by generalizing your selector, so instead of adding the event to `$('input[name=addItem]')` (Meaning: To all tags of type "input" with an attribute "name" set to "additem") you can for example use `$('input[type=text]')` which will bind your event to all input-tags with attribute "type" set to "text".

Depending on your application, would you want to change the suggested auto-completes based on which input-field is being clicked on? That'd need more logic in your event handler.

Comment: `$('input[type=text]')` will bind autocomplete to all appropriate `input` s that exist at the DOM when that method is fired. So when the OP dynamically adds a new `input` it will not have an autcomplete bound to it. -------- Note the second `input` in this example ==> http://jsfiddle.net/fbG5h/

Comment: True, I interpreted the question to as all the DOM-elements were present when attached.

Comment: Since the code includes `$('#list').append(divCloned);`, new elements are being added to the DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Copy the original autocomplete

You can make a **[`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** that includes event handlers using `.clone(true)`:

```
var divCloned = $('#line-1').clone(true);
```

This should include the autocomplete for `#line-1`, so with the line above replacing the corresponding line in your code you should be all set.

---

**Option 2:** Create a new autocomplete with different options

If you want to change the autocomplete functionality, you can just set it again:

```
var divCloned = $('#line-1').clone(); // <== Don't copy the event handlers.

// ... do things, set variables, append divCloned, whatever

  // Now set the autocomplete with different options from the original
divCloned.autocomplete({ ... });
```

Comment: Why would you want to make/clone n _equal_ event handlers for n inputs? Just use the same. And creating a new handler for each input is what he's trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @sagen - You would have to use `live()` or `.delegate()` to add autocomplete to all now and future `input` s, and that's probably just as expensive.... `$("input").autcomplete(...)` would only add autocomplete for elements in the DOM at that point in time, then when you create a new `input` you have to somehow add handlers to it. ---- I haven't used the `.autocomplete()` plugin, so I'm not sure how it'd work with `.live()` or `.delegate()`.

Comment: You only have to attach the existing event handler to your newly created elements, so var handler = func(e){}, div1.autoComplete(handler); div2.autoComplete(handler); has less overhead than cloning.

Comment: @sagen - I'm not sure about that. It seems like they're very similar, since cloning with the `true` argument attaches the existing handler to the new element... which is what you are saying. Also, I don't quite get that code snippet.